# What are the Big Theorems in Information Geometry?

Tags: soft-question, motivation, information-geometry

I am working on preparing a talk on information geometry to a young finance/applied math audience. Motivating this area is turning out to be a little difficult.

***What are some big theorems or results that I should be covering?***

Any help is appreciated, especially since this field is probably not too well-known.

Comment: Did you try the monographs by Amari and by Amari and Nagaoka?

Answer (score 0):

The 2018 [elementary introduction to information geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08271) by [Frank Nielsen](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/) seems to constitute an adequate answer to your question (too late for you talk though, but may be useful for new viewers).

It contains a subsection called **The fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry: The Levi-Civita metric connection** in the differential geometry prerequisite section so I guess it means it's quite fundamental for Information Geometry.

As a new IG user coming from machine learning, I didn't use actual theorems yet but I guess a talk focused on one field of application should detail the manifolds, metrics, geodesics, etc necessary to work with IG. (Typically, I was looking for information related to the SPD matrices manifold when I first opened Amari's [Information Geometry and Its Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-55978-8), SPD matrices being a relevant representation in computer vision).